SHA256 mismatch for "conda install pytorch"
I'm trying to install pytorch+cuda12.1 in my conda env.
I've followed the instructions on https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ and ran the following command:
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=12.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia

The command runs smoothly for most packages, except for cuda-version, for which i get:
ChecksumMismatchError: Conda detected a mismatch between the expected content and downloaded content
for url 'https://conda.anaconda.org/nvidia/noarch/cuda-version-12.5-3.tar.bz2'.
  download saved to: C:\Users\UserName\anaconda3\pkgs\cuda-version-12.5-3.tar.bz2
  expected sha256: f13836396c27d22ff8fd446534aa3cdc0c92b1d68e5181ff2680da4c2759b117
  actual sha256: a85ae72fb1b40651095208ebe42cd595980a916e324505610ac8fc76c49164f5

I checked https://conda.anaconda.org/nvidia/noarch/, and it seems that the actual SHA256 is correct, and the expected SHA256 is actually the wrong one:



Filename
Size
Last Modified
SHA256
MD5




cuda-version-12.5-3.tar.bz2
16 KB
2024-04-16 03:01:46 +0000
a85ae72fb1b40651095208ebe42cd595980a916e324505610ac8fc76c49164f5
be95c91143996f0c33cb710cd1a39450



I found some old issues about how the PyTorch maintainers had some issues uploading some time ago, but it was supposed to be fixed already.
Is there something I can do to fix this issue?

You could always pin cuda-version to another channel.
conda install -c pytorch -c nvidia conda-forge::cuda-version=12.5 torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=12.1 


Thanks, this workaround worked just fine!
